# How to update configuration xml file in a Lantronix xport-pro devices

Tags: java, ftp, java-io

I want to manually update the xml configuration file for Lantronix Xport-pro devices.

I have some process tu upload the file by Java FTP.

My question is: When I upload the file, what is needed to run the update of the xml configuration file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

To perform an upgrade of the xport-pro lantronix configuration devices, the XCR file import option must be enabled. This option is found on the Lantronix configuration web page, on the TFTP tab, Select enabled option in the checkbox, then click on the Submit button.

The .xml configuration file can be renamed as an .xcr file. When transferring this file via FTP or tftp, the device automatically runs the configuration and restarts the device.